# Adobe Edge how to disable auto play by code?

Tags: javascript, events, adobe-edge

I have an Adobe Edge animation that is playing automatically by default.

Is there a way to disable or prevent the auto play by javascript code?

For example by passing some option when loading the composition with `AdobeEdge.loadComposition()` or by setting some event listener that will do this?

*P.S. I do not have the ability to edit the animation itself in Adobe Edge*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by adding a `compositionReady` listener. This event is taking place before the auto play, so I can influence the auto play settings of the animation.

I've put the code below right after calling `AdobeEdge.loadComposition()`. The timeout here is set to 2000 milliseconds. The solution works with animations having child symbols (using `sym.ci` which holds a reference to the child symbols).

```
AdobeEdge.bootstrapCallback(function(compId){
    AdobeEdge.Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, 'stage', 'document', 'compositionReady', function(sym, e){
        sym.stopAll(-1, false);
        sym.setAutoPlay(false);
        if (sym.ci) {
            for(var i = 0; i < sym.ci.length; ++i) {
                sym.ci[i].setAutoPlay(false);
            }
        }
        var playDelay = setTimeout(function(){
            sym.playAll();
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```